# jQuery template: Creating a conditional statement with OR operators

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

This works:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{if ON}} checked {{/if}} id="cbCentral" />
```

This doesn't work:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{if ON || QC}} checked {{/if}} id="cbCentral" />
```

It seems || cannot be used to represent an OR operator. How can I express an OR operator in jQuery template?